# I have a problem with the java code I just imported

Tags: jgraphx

Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library (java-11-openjdk-amd64]' in project 'Test Compilation'

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed java-11-openjdk? If so you can do the following

1. Right-click on your project –> Build Path –>Configure Build Path
2. Select JRE Library -> click Edit  -> Edit library
3. Choose the JRE which has been downloaded and installed -> click finish